# Java maze game-- How to not go through the wall

Tags: java, collision, maze

So for a class project, I'm making a solvable maze game (in Java).  I can randomly generate and display the maze without a problem, and the same goes for the user/player's representation.  However, the problem I'm having is with the individual walls of the maze.

I need to make sure that the player can't go through the walls.  I've looked around, and it seems a lot of people have similar problems, but they are using a grid structure to make their mazes.  I'm not --my maze's walls are just lines, so I can't do what everybody else is doing, (just see if a certain cell in the maze is already occupied --I don't have cells to check).

What I do have is both end points of the line --the starting x, starting y, ending x, and ending y-- and the current point of the upper left corner of the circle that represents the player.  I also have the point of the proposed new upper left corner of the circle.

I need to know if the player is going to cross any of the lines that represent walls.  At the moment, I loop through an array that contains all of the walls.  Given the current player position and proposed player position, I need to find out if that involves crossing a wall.  Any tips/hints/help would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you're talking about a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your world is 2D,

```
[] [] []|[]
      -----
[] [] [] []

[] [] [] []

[] [] [] []
```

and | and --- are walls

Method #1: enlarge your grid to include the wall intersections. So the size of the row and columns will be row+(row-1),col+(col-1)

this is your new array representation:
Original row = 4, new row = 4+3 = 7. This will also create walls to check for diagonal movements.

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][|][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][-][-][-]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Method #2: using the 4x4 representation, create a wall class that stores the adjacent tiles coordinate. And after that create a list to store a list of walls.

```
Wall(Point x,Point y); // constructor
Wall wall1 = new Wall(new Point(0,2),new Point(0,3));
Wall wall2 = new Wall(new Point(0,2),new Point(1,2));
Wall wall3 = new Wall(new Point(0,3),new Point(1,3));
```

this representation, allows you to create rules such that 0,0 can go to 1,1 but 0,1 cannot go to 1,0. 
If you want a unidirectional wall, which might sound silly but who knows? You can modify your wall class constructor:

```
Wall(Point from,Point to);
```

Collision checking for method 1:
when moving your character, after you move, if it lands on the wall, don't allow the movement.

Collision checking for method 2:
when moving your character, cache where the character is from, and where the character will move to if the move is allowed, construct a new Wall object base on that and check if the Wall list contains the new Wall object.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a line segment (x1, x2), where x1 is the player's current position, and x2 is the location the player is attempting to move to. Any move through a wall would have this line segment intersect the wall segment. You can therefore validate a move by checking (x1, x2) for intersection against all maze walls (a linear-time task).

Checking segment intersection is easy, and there is a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) explaining how to implement it.

If you can add any additional information (for example maximum length of walls), you can store the maze in such a way that you would not have to query **all** walls for intersection. For example, if walls are either horizontal or vertical, and moves are as well, you need only check horizontal walls in case of a vertical move.

Hope this helps!